Py4JJavaError, Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[26], line 1 ----> 1 emp.show()
I am new to pyspark and facing an issue when I call df.show():
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark Introduction").master("local[*]").config("spark.network.timeout", "800s").config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "60s").getOrCreate()
)
data = [("Alice", 34), ("Bob", 45), ("Catherine", 29)]
columns = ["Name", "Age"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.show()

Each line is running fine but i am getting error in the line df.show() only. I am using python3.10 with pyspark version 3.4.3 with java 11. All the paths are added to the system environment variable. I have tried 3.12 and 3.10 python version. but facing the same problem from last 7 days. I am getting error of Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[53], line 1
----> 1 emp.show()
File c:\Users\Bharti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:947, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    887 def show(self, n: int = 20, truncate: Union[bool, int] = True, vertical: bool = False) -> None:
    888     """Prints the first ``n`` rows to the console.
    889 
    890     .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
   (...)
    945     name | Bob
    946     """
--> 947     print(self._show_string(n, truncate, vertical))

File c:\Users\Bharti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:965, in DataFrame._show_string(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    959     raise PySparkTypeError(
    960         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    961         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
    962     )
    964 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 965     return self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical)
    966 else:
    967     try:

File c:\Users\Bharti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File c:\Users\Bharti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File c:\Users\Bharti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (DESKTOP-DARCLVU executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:583)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:749)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:757)
    ... 24 more


what error are you getting? can you include the full traceback?

Yes question has been edited. Kindly refer that.
